# Selenium wait until API responses

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I wanna check for API responses and then click on a specific button, so the button is present, no need for visibility check, but the API still checking for some validity in the background. 
My step definitiion is"

```
@And("^I click on Describe your Shipment button$")
public void i_click_on_describe_your_shipment_button() {
    Button.safeClick(driver, destinationLocation.describeYourShipmentButton());}
```

I have tried:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but has not worked.

The only thing works for me:

```
Thread.sleep()
```

which I dont want to use. 
Any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to solve that in Selenium, but you can get rid of that Thread.sleep with **Awaitility**.

Example from their Github page:

```
@Test
public void updatesCustomerStatus() {
    // Publish an asynchronous message to a broker (e.g. RabbitMQ):
    messageBroker.publishMessage(updateCustomerStatusMessage);
    // Awaitility lets you wait until the asynchronous operation completes:
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(customerStatusIsUpdated());
    ...
}
```

Details here: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility